# OpenCV copying submatrix into another ROI of image

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, copy

I need to move a submatrix of the image to another place of the same image: it means move down this sumbmatrix. So I have developed the next code

```
Mat image;
image = cv::imread(buffer, 1);

nlines = 10;

for ( k = 0; k < nlines; k++ ) 
{
    for ( j = 401; j < ncolmax; j++ )
    {
        for ( i = nrowmax-1; i >= 555 ; i--)
        {
            intensity = image.at<uchar>(i-1,j);
            image.at<uchar>(i,j) = intensity.val[0];
        }
        image.at<uchar>(i,j) = 255;
     }
}
```

the correct image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/daFMw.png

However, in order to improve the speed of the code, I would like to work with copies of submatrices and I have implemented this code:

```
Mat aux = image.colRange(pixel[1],image.cols-1).rowRange(pixel[0]+nlineas,nrowmax-1);

Mat newsubmatrix = image.colRange(pixel[1],image.cols-1).rowRange(pixel[0],nrowmax-1-nlineas);

newsubmatrix.copyTo(aux);
```

which does not work correctly as you can see in the picture-link below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gr9P.png

Comment: can you post also the original image?

Comment: Of course, here you have the original image:  http://imgur.com/mIwM5GB

Comment: What are the 3 loops doing? the `k` loop seems useless, while the `i` and `j` loops seem to just copy the image row down one pixel at a time. Is that the intention?

Comment: Probably would be easier to answer if you provide also the coordinates of the ROI before and after the translation, since nrowmax and ncolmax are not specified in the snippet you posted

Comment: Exactly. The intention is to move k-rows the sumatrix choosen. It means that the k-loop move the submatrix one row down each time. Of course, I know this method is not efficient, but I'm newbie with the library and I'm trying different ways to do same.

Comment: image size 800x800 so image.rows = 800 and image.cols = 800 -->  ROI. nrowmin = 555 ncolmin = 401 nrowmax=800 ncolmax = 800

Comment: Still not so clear what you want to do. So you want to move rows down `nlines`? If so, which rows? I need the coordinates of the submatrix before and after the translation

Comment: from the row (nrowmin=555) to the bottom border of the matrix. In addition only fos pixels between the column (ncolmin = 401) to the left border of the matrix.  As I told before  
image size is 800x800 so `image.rows = 800` and `image.cols = 800` --> ROI. `nrowmin = 555` `ncolmin = 401` `nrowmax=800` `ncolmax = 800` and `pixel[1] = ncolmin = 401`. Summararizing, the ROI I want to move down `nlines` has these coordinates: top left corner: (555, 401) and bottom right corner: (800, 800).

Comment: Have a look at my answer, and see if it's clearer what I meant with position of the submatrix before and after the translation. You just need to insert your coordinates for the two rects, and you should be good to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you copy a portion of the image from position `rectBefore` to position `rectAfter`.

You just need to specify the `x` and `y` coordinates of the two rectangles, as well as `width` and `height` (that must be equal in both).

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat3b img = imread("path_to_image");

    int roi_width = 200;
    int roi_height = 100;
    Rect rectBefore(270, 100, roi_width, roi_height);
    Rect rectAfter(500, 400, roi_width, roi_height);

    Mat3b dbg1 = img.clone();
    rectangle(dbg1, rectBefore, Scalar(0,255,0), 2);

    Mat3b roiBefore = img(rectBefore).clone();  // Copy the data in the source position
    Mat3b roiAfter = img(rectAfter);            // Get the header to the destination position

    roiBefore.copyTo(roiAfter);

    Mat3b dbg2 = img.clone();
    rectangle(dbg2, rectAfter, Scalar(0,0,255), 2);

    return 0;
}
```

This will copy the portion of the image in the green rectangle `rectBefore` to the red rectangle `rectAfter`.

**dbg1**

[image]

**dbg2**

[image]